# Eclipse : Getting Error as Could not find jar file while installing Plugin in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, visualvm

I was following this below website 
http://visualvm.java.net/eclipse-launcher.html
for installing VisualVM into Eclipse Helios Version 3.6 , for this as mentioned i downloaded visualvm_launcher_u1_eclipse_36 
and also under in Eclipse Menu Window --->Preferences ---> Installed JRE ---> Pointed JDK Path in JRE Settings
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27

But when i tried to install this VisualVM into Eclipse by

Eclipse Menu ---> Install New Software --->Add -- >Archive  option

i am getting the below exception

Could not find jar file:file:/D:/VisualVM/visualvm_launcher_u1_eclipse_36.zip!/

Please see the image related to the Exception .

[image]

Answer (score 7):

This is what I did to get it installed.

1. downloaded and unzipped to C:/visualvm_launcher_u1_eclipse_36/
2. Eclipse Window --->Preferences ---> Available Software Sites --> Add
   (Name: VisualVM; 
   Location: file:/C:/visualvm_launcher_u1_eclipse_36/)
3. Eclipse Help ---> Install New Software ---> Select VisualVM from drop-down menu ---> Expand Uncategorized ---> Select VisualVM Launcher Feature ---> Next

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are not following the steps for installation. You should:

1. unzip visualvm_launcher_u1_eclipse_36.zip into directory of your choice
2. add local update site pointing to the chosen directory
3. install VisualVM Launcher Feature

Comment: I am still having this issue. please help

Answer (score 0):

The file itself may be corrupt that you are trying to add as an archive.  Examine the root level of the file and make sure the correct components are there.  Right now, I am trying to install EPIC in such a way.  What I see in the zip file at the root level are:

- features (folder)
- plugins (folder)
- README.txt (file)
- site.xml (file)

Answer (score 0):

For anybody else stumbling upon this question and having the same problems:

- handshake failure when using Eclipse marketplace/Update site
- You tried JRE unlimited policy workaround and it doesn't work
- manual installation of plugins also doesn't work

I have downloaded clean eclipse zip, started it and downloaded the plugin that I wanted (Enhanced Class Decompiler), and then opened the targeted Eclipse installation (actually an IDE called Intershop Studio) and used File -> Import -> Installation -> From Existing Installation to import plugins.

So this solution is applicable if problems are not caused by system configuration or if you already have plugins installed on another Eclipse installation.