# Unable to install Jumble tool Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, eclipse-plugin, mutation-testing

I am trying to use jumble tool with but unable to use install it in eclipse.I am following the steps given here.
http://jumble.sourceforge.net/
now when i try to add jumble link into add new software option i get error .
cannot find http://jumble.sourceforge.net.

Can anyone please help me with this ?

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse

Go to *Help > Install New Software*

Copy this link https://sourceforge.net/projects/jumble/files/jumble/1.3.0/

The link provided in the official documentation (http://jumble.sourceforge.net/update/) was not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

The error you see is the following:

```
Unable to read repository at http://jumble.sourceforge.net/update/content.xml.
Unable to read repository at http://jumble.sourceforge.net/update/content.xml.
Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

This is because of new SSL policies added by **SourceForge**. Indeed, in January 2017 they did a change in the security settings used by their download servers.

The problem is caused by SourceForge mandating the use of strong encryption, while the Oracle JDK, due to export restrictions, is not able to handle strong encryption.

As stated [here](https://gnu-mcu-eclipse.github.io/blog/2017/01/29/plugins-install-issue/):

> The solution is to install the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files. In practical terms, this means replacing two JAR files in the JRE /lib/security folder.

Alternatively you could download and install the plugin manually.

For example you can download the update site as a zip archive, unpack it locally and use this folder as an update site.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42128981/eclipse-pmd-plug-in-handshake-failure) as a similar problem with another Eclipse plugin and the relative solution.