# I am not able to add evosuite plugin to my eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, evosuite

1. I installed eclipse Luna
2. downloaded evosuite jar from https://www.evosuite.org/update/
3. Added this jar to my project project-->build path-->configure build path-->Libraries-->Add external jars
   4)Eclipse -->help-->InstallNew software-->Ad->Archive-->
   Name:evosuite
   location:jar:file:/C:/Users/SRAVANI/Documents/Eclipse plugin/org.evosuite.plugins.eclipse.core_1.0.7.201806011952.jar!/
   5)error:"couldn't find jar
4. for resolving the above error I downloaded visualVM as suggested in [Eclipse : Getting Error as Could not find jar file while installing Plugin in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680497/eclipse-getting-error-as-could-not-find-jar-file-while-installing-plugin-in-ec)
5. I am facing the same error as i faced before for adding visualVM also
6. As a last try I Imported the evosuite.jar into the project and added to classpath
   I am not able to get that generate tests with evosuite option as mentioned in this link
   https://github.com/EvoSuite/evosuite/issues/136

Can someone please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

Install New Software is the only correct way to install a plug-in.

Do not download the jar, instead enter the address of the update site `https://www.evosuite.org/update/` in to the 'Work with' field on the Install New Software dialog (and press Enter). The dialog will then show you what can be installed from that location.

Note that Eclipse Luna is now 6 years and 12 releases old, the plug-in might require a newer release.

What the Install New Software dialog should show:
[image: Example install new software dialog]

Comment: what is the eclipse version that you used as mentioned in the image

Comment: The current Eclipse 2020-06 release (dark theme on macOS other systems may look a bit different). I have not tested if the plug-in installs or works, only that it shows in the install dialog.

Comment: When I gave https://www.evosuite.org/update/ I am not getting the evosuite plugin in the drop down . may be due to version compatability. Can you please mention the eclipse,JRE and JDK versions that u used in your system.

Comment: You must press enter when you have typed `https://www.evosuite.org/update/` in to Work with field, you will always get something appearing in the 'Name' section even if it is just 'nothing found'. I have already told you I am using Eclipse 2020-06, the JRE/JDK is not relevant.

Comment: This is really helpful and I am able to install the plugin successfully.
but i am not able to get generate tests with evosuite option on right click of a java file.after the plugin is installed successfuly.